# Replace dots using `gsub`

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I am trying to replace all the "." in a specific column of my data frame with "/". There are other characters in each cell and I want to make sure I only change the "."'s.
When I use gsub, I get an output that appears to make the changes, but then when I go to View(), the changes are not actually made...I thought gsub was supposed to actually change the value in the data frame. Am I using it incorrectly? I have my code below.

```
gsub(".", "/", spy$Identifier, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE,
    fixed = TRUE, useBytes = FALSE)
```

I also tried sub, but the code I have below changed every entry itself to "/" and I am not sure how to change it.

```
spy$Identifier <- sub("^(.).*", "/", spy$Identifier)
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend `chartr()` instead of `gsub()`, since it's a one-to-one character translation. `chartr(".", "/", spy$Identifier)` and you're done.

Comment: We can't  really go much further until you provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Never mind, the answer below worked...Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just to state the obvious, remember that `R` doesn't act *by reference*. So, if you just try your line *without assigning the result back*, you won't obtain anything. Try the line suggested by @RichardScriven: see that the result of `chartr` is assigned to `spy$Identifier`.

Comment: Ok yes @nicola that was what I was forgetting. The output was confusing me. I am teaching myself R for my job so apologies for the confusion....All of these answers work now

Comment: `gsub(".", "/", spy$Identifier,fixed = TRUE)` should work too. I don't get it.

Comment: @DavidArenburg see my comment. Guess the issue was just due to the fact that they run the line without assigning the result back.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My recommendation would be to escape the "." character:

```
        spy$Identifier <- gsub("\\.", "/", spy$Identifier)
```

In regular expression, a period is a special character that matches any character. "Escaping" it tells the search to look for an actual period.  In R's gsub this is accomplished with two backslashes (i.e.: "\\").  In other languages, it's often just one backslash.

Comment: I don't get it, OP already used `fixed = TRUE`. That should work too. And it is much more efficient than escaping dot- hence the recommended solution usually.